# Generic Stacks in C

Tags: c, generics, stack

I am implementing generic stack in C and I am facing a problem in stackPop method. My struct is as follows:

**"Stack.h" file**

```
        typedef struct{
            void *elems;
            int elemSize;
            int allocLength;
            int logLength;
            void (*freefnc)(void *);
        } Stack;

    void stackNew(Stack *s, int elemSize, void (*freefnc)(void *));
    void stackDispose(Stack *s);
    void stackPush(Stack *s, void *elemAddr);
    void stackPop(Stack *s, void *target);
```

**Stack.c**

```
    #inlcude<Stack.h>

    void stackNew(Stack *s, int elemSize, void (*freefnc)(void *)){
        s.allocLength = 4;
        s.logLength = 0;
        s.elemSize = elemSize;
        s.elems = malloc(4*elemSize);
        s.freefnc =  freefnc;
    }

    void stackDispose(Stack *s){
        if(s.freefnc!=NULL){
            for(int i=0; i<s.logLength; i++){
                freefnc((char *)s.elems+i*s->elemSize);
            }
        }
        free(s.elems);
    }

    void Stringfree(void *elem){
        free(*(char**)elem);
    }

    void stackPush(Stack *s, void *elemAddr){
        if(s.alloclength == s.logLength){
            stackGrow(s);
        }
        void *target = (char *)s.elems + s.logLength*s.elemSize;
        memcpy(target,elemAddr,s.elemSize);
        s.logLength++;
    }

    static void stackGrow(Stack *s){
        s.allocLength*=2;
        s.elems = realloc(s.elems, s.alloclength*s.elemSize);
        assert(s.elems!=NULL);
    }

    void stackPop(Stack *s, void *elemAddr){
        void *source = (char *)s.elems + (s.logLength-1)*s.elemSize;
        memcpy(elemAddr,source,s.elemSize);
        s.logLength--;
    }
```

How do I return/get the value being popped off in **stackPop** function? I do not want to change the implementation but if there is a good way which keeps the implementation same to the extent as much as possible, then I would appreciate that. Other approaches are also acceptable.

Comment: It would make more sense to simply return a value in `stackPop`.. Why must the implementation remain the same?

Comment: @Vulcan he probably meant the implementation of the stack, not the function.

Comment: That would be good but I thought over this for a while and if you feel that concept is not changed by changing the implementation, then can you provide me with a better approach?

Comment: I want my implementation of stack to be same to as much extent as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a problem with making it mirror `stackPush`. What is wrong with the current approach?

Comment: `stackGrow` will leak memory if `realloc` fails, and then `stackPush` will crash.  `allocLength *= 2` can also overflow but you're more likely to run out of memory first.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with current approach but I am not able to find a way to get the popped off value because the return type is _void_.

Comment: The point of a `void*` is that the actual type of the memory pointed to is left unspecified.  If your stack contains `int`s then do: `int i; stackPop(s, &i);` - `i` will receive the value.

Comment: @asveikau: is it fine now? I have added an assert statement. And thanx :D

Comment: so, uh, are *you* implementing the generic stack, or using someone else's code?

Comment: The header you mentioned in the question is Stack.h and the headr you have included in your .c file is "StringStack.h". Dont you think something's wrong?? :-)

Comment: sorry, i wrote that wrong. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @nneonneo i am implementing my own generic stack code. If I would have used someone else's code then I would not have any knowledge about it!!

Comment: Well...you 'wrote' `stackPop` and don't seem to know how to use it?

Comment: Also, what the heck is up with the header file? You're actually defining functions there with empty bodies, not just declaring them...

Comment: @nneonneo I was confused about how to use it when I have a stack for Integers or Strings. And I don't need to prove to you that I am writing my own code!

Comment: OK, are you using your own interface (that you defined), or someone else's interface?

Comment: this is my own interface. I have reading about how to do things in generics and that's why I was getting a problem. If you have a problem with that then stop bugging me!

Comment: @nneonneo- Nice catch man. To Vaibhav- Bhai, remove the last braces which are used to embody the function functionality....oops m out of words I think :-)

Comment: These comments should stop here. Its getting personal.

Comment: I saw in some comments you mentioned that this is your personal implementation of a stack, but i've seen the exact same code in some of the stanford's lectures.You clearly copy-pasted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best you could do is to return a pointer to popped data (as a `void*` since that's about the best you can do in C for a 'generic' function):

```
void* stackPop(Stack *s, void *elemAddr){
        void *source = (char *)s.elems + (s.logLength-1)*s.elemSize;
        memcpy(elemAddr,source,s.elemSize);
        s.logLength--;
        return elemAddr;
}
```

Note that the caller still needs to provide the memory and the address to pop the data into; if you want ed you could avoid that by having the function `malloc()` the memory:

```
void* stackPop(Stack *s){
        void *source = (char *)s.elems + (s.logLength-1)*s.elemSize;
        void *elemAddr = malloc(s.elemSize);
        // if (!elemAddr) handle_error();
        memcpy(elemAddr,source,s.elemSize);
        s.logLength--;
        return elemAddr;
}
```

Of course that would require the caller to `free()` it when it is no longer needed, and adds the minor complication of needing to handle the out of memory situation.