# What Is Wrong in the "free" Function for this Generic Stack Implementation in C?

Tags: c, stack, free

I have the following implementation of a generic stack, i.e, the stack can store user-specified data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct{
    void *elems;
    int elemSize;
    int allocLength;
    int logLength;
    void (*freefnc) ( void* );
} Stack;

void stackNew( Stack* s, int elemSize, void (*freefnc) (void*) ){
    s->allocLength = 4;
    s->logLength = 0;
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->elems = malloc( s->allocLength * elemSize );
    s->freefnc = freefnc;
}

void stackDispose( Stack* s ){
    if( s->freefnc ){
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < s->logLength; i++ ){
            s->freefnc( ( char* ) s->elems + i * s->elemSize   );
        }
    }
    free( s->elems );
}

void stackGrow( Stack* s){
    s->allocLength *= 2;
    s->elems = realloc( s->elems, s->allocLength * s->elemSize );
    assert( s->elems != NULL );
}

void stackPush( Stack* s, void* elemAddr ){
    if( s->allocLength == s->logLength ){
        stackGrow( s );
    }
    void *target = (char*) s->elems + s->logLength * s->elemSize;
    memcpy( target, elemAddr, s->elemSize );
    s->logLength++;
}

void* stackPop( Stack* s ){
    void* source = (char*) s->elems + ( s->logLength - 1 ) * s->elemSize;
    void* elemAddr = malloc( s->elemSize );
    assert( elemAddr != NULL );
    memcpy( elemAddr, source, s->elemSize );
    s->logLength--;
    return elemAddr;
}

void freeInt( void* p ){
    char* q = p;
    free( q );
}

void stackPrint( Stack* s ){
    printf( "elemSize: %d\n", s->elemSize );
    printf( "allocLength: %d\n", s->allocLength );
    printf( "logLength: %d\n", s->logLength );

    int i;
    for( i=0; i < s->logLength; i++ ){
        printf("%d\n", *( (char*) s->elems + i * s->elemSize ) );
    }
}

int main(){
    Stack st;
    stackNew( &st, 4, &freeInt );
    int elem = 5;
    int elem2 = 9;
    stackPush( &st, &elem );
    stackPush( &st, &elem2);
    stackPrint( &st );
    stackDispose( &st );
}
```

However, I got the output below when running the code.

```
elemSize: 4
allocLength: 4
logLength: 2
5
9
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000014b9014 ***
Aborted
```

It seems something wrong in the "freefnc" in the code but I am not sure. Can anybody explain what is wrong in the code and how to fix it?

P.S. The code is adopted from another SO post [Generic Stacks in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614893/generic-stacks-in-c). I am trying to understand how the code works. It will be highly appreciated if anybody can give a working version of the code with test cases.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're calling `free` on a pointer that was not returned by `malloc`.

Comment: (Actually, the first time `freeInt` is called it's for a pointer that *was* returned by `malloc`, and the first call to `freeInt` ends up freeing the stack's entire data array)

Comment: `stackDispose()` should only contain a single `free` call, and no loop. (The stack is a vector, not a list of pointers to elements.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's be clear on how your stack is stored in memory: You have a `Stack` object (whose memory isn't actually managed by the `stack` functions but by whatever "owns" the stack), and a single big memory block holding all of the elements (and some empty space).

In ASCII art form:

```
+-----------------------+
| elems | ............. |    <- Stack object
+---|-------------------+
    |
    V
    +---------------------------------+
    | elem1 | elem2 | unused | unused |    <- Data array
    +---------------------------------+
```

`elems` in the `Stack` object holds a pointer to the start of the data array.

To destroy this stack, all you need to do is destroy the data array (which was malloc-ed, so use `free`), and the `Stack` object (which is a local variable, so it's destroyed when the function that contains it returns).

There is no need to free all the individual elements. They will be destroyed as part of the data array. Calling `free` on the individual elements is *wrong*; if you try to `free` the first element you end up freeing the whole array, and if you try to `free` the other elements you end up causing undefined behaviour.

---

You might be wondering why `freefnc` is useful, then. `freefnc` is useful if the stack elements are themselves pointers (or structs that contain pointers). Say, if you were storing strings allocated with `malloc`:

```
+-----------------------+
| elems | ............. |    <- Stack object
+---|-------------------+
    |
    V
    +---------------------------------+
    | elem1 | elem2 | unused | unused |    <- Data array
    +---|-------|---------------------+
        |       |
        |       V
        |       +------------+
        |       |w|o|r|l|d|\0|    <- second string
        |       +------------+       (allocated with malloc)
        V
        +------------+
        |H|e|l|l|o|\0|    <- first string (allocated with malloc)
        +------------+
```

In that case, you'd want to set up `freefnc` to `free` the strings themselves (but still not the actual stack elements). Of course, you currently don't have this situation, since you're just storing `int`s in your stack.

Comment: I tried:  char* elem = malloc( 6 * sizeof(char) ); strcpy( elem, "Hello\0" ); char* elem2 = malloc( 6 * sizeof(char) ); strcpy( elem2, "World\0" );  stackPush( &st, elem ); stackPush( &st, elem2); stackDispose( &st );  and still got Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000242c016 *** Aborted. Anything wrong in the definition or use of freeInt or freefnc?

Comment: @leo Try making sure the element size is sizeof(char*), instead of 4. (It won't be 4 on a 64-bit system!) Also, you want to `free(*(char**)p);` - `p` is a pointer to the stack element i.e. a pointer to a pointer to the string you want to free.

Comment: Also note: you need to free the pointer returned by `stackPop`, because `stackPop` calls `malloc` and returns that pointer.

Comment: I wrote `void stringFree( void* elem ){free( *( char** ) elem );}` and call  `stackNew( &st, sizeof(char*), stringFree)` in main; But I got `Segmentation fault`. Moreover, in the implementation `void*` is always cast to `(char*)` for any pointer arithmetic, e.g., line `s->freefnc( ( char* ) s->elems + i * s->elemSize );` in `stackDispose`. I am wondering why (if) it has to be `(char*)`? If the stack elements are `int*`, does the cast type still work? I think it should be, otherwise the implementation is not **generic**. Am I right?

Comment: Using GDB, the address `(char**) elem` in `stringFree` is reported **not accessible**. Any  idea about why and how to fix this?

Comment: @leo Make sure you're storing a pointer to the string in the stack, not trying to store the string itself?