# Generic Stack stops popping values

Tags: c, generics

I'm trying to build a generic stack but my pop-method seems wrong cause it prints the numbers from 100 to 1 and the 1 double.
If I change the pop-method to this solution: [Generic Stacks in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614893/generic-stacks-in-c) it pops to 64 and then just 64 times 0.

struct:

```
typedef struct {
    void *elems;
    int elemSize;
    int logLength;
    int allocLength;
    void (*freefn)(void*);
} genStack;
```

C-Source file:

```
#include "genstacklib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void GenStackNew(genStack *s, int elemSize, void(*freefn)(void *)) {
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->elems = malloc(4 * s->elemSize);
    if (s->elems == NULL) {
        perror("\n\nError: ");
    }
    s->allocLength = 4 * s->elemSize;
    s->logLength = 0;
    s->freefn = freefn;
}

void GenStackDispose(genStack *s) {
    if (s->elems == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nStack is not initialized!\n\n");
        return;
    }
    /*if (s->freefn != NULL) {
        int n = 0;
        while (s->logLength != 0) {
            freefn(s->elems + n * s->elemSize);
            n++;
        }
    }*/
    free(s->elems);
}

bool GenStackEmpty(const genStack *s) {
    if (s->logLength == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void GenStackPush(genStack *s, const void *elemAddr) {
    if (s->elems == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nStack not initialized!\n\n");
        return;
    }
    if (s->allocLength == s->logLength * s->elemSize) {
        s->allocLength = 2*s->allocLength;
        s->elems = realloc(s->elems, s->allocLength*s->elemSize);
    }
    memcpy(s->elems+s->logLength*s->elemSize,elemAddr,s->elemSize);
    s->logLength++;
}

void GenStackPop(genStack *s, void *elemAddr) {
    void *source = s->elems + (s->logLength-1)*s->elemSize;
    memcpy(elemAddr,source,s->elemSize);
    memcpy(s->elems,source,s->elemSize);
    s->logLength--;
    //memcpy((char*)s->elems+(s->logLength-1)*s->elemSize,elemAddr,s->elemSize);
}
```

Test stack (should push numbers from 0 to 100 and pop it afterwards):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int val;
    genStack IntegerStack;

    GenStackNew(&IntegerStack, sizeof(int), NULL);
    for (val = 0; val < 100; val++) {
        GenStackPush(&IntegerStack, &val);
        printf("Pushed: %d\n",val);
    }

    while(!GenStackEmpty(&IntegerStack)){
        GenStackPop(&IntegerStack, &val);
        printf("Popped: %d\n",val);
    }

    GenStackDispose(&IntegerStack);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second memcpy call in the GenStackPop function seems redundant and does nothing but clobber the first element:

```
memcpy(s->elems,source,s->elemSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I get compiler warnings that the size of `void *` is not known when required. This occurrs in:

```
memcpy(s->elems+s->logLength*s->elemSize,elemAddr,s->elemSize);
```

as you use `+` on `s->elems` and in pop.

Change `void *elems;` in the struct declaration to `char *elems;` and it works OK.

Comment: OP is using a compiler extension.

Comment: @2501, this extensions equates on these ocassions `void *` to `char *`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the compiler problem. I'm casting now the void* to a char* and it works.